# Wireless constantly reconnecting on Ideapad running Arch

Tags: linux, kernel

I just bought a new laptop, a Lenovo IdeaPad U330 touch, and after some struggle (with the Secure Boot stupidity) I have managed to install Arch Linux. I have configured my system, installed all the drivers (I think), but 
I have a problem with my wireless disconnecting from the network.

I have noticed that my `dmesg` is being spammed with the

```
ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
```

Also, somewhere in the flood of all those messages, there appears

```
mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
```

but searching for the latter, there was a known bug and it's supposed to be fixed in the 3.14 version of the kernel.

I don't know if those messages are related to my wireless issues but I thought they might be relevant. I'm pasting the last few lines of dmesg with wireless reconnecting:

```
[ 2513.577794] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
[ 2534.762183] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
[ 2555.958244] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
[ 2577.159613] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
[ 2580.083918] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 2580.918208] wlp2s0: authenticate with 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0
[ 2580.920015] wlp2s0: send auth to 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0 (try 1/3)
[ 2580.924404] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 2580.931245] wlp2s0: associate with 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0 (try 1/3)
[ 2580.957371] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=10)
[ 2580.968632] wlp2s0: associated
[ 2598.361115] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
[ 2619.550989] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
[ 2621.534185] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 2622.369409] wlp2s0: authenticate with 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0
[ 2622.371192] wlp2s0: send auth to 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0 (try 1/3)
[ 2622.375724] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 2622.378073] wlp2s0: associate with 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0 (try 1/3)
[ 2622.426904] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=10)
[ 2622.428139] wlp2s0: associated
[ 2624.830025] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 2625.652178] wlp2s0: authenticate with 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0
[ 2625.653835] wlp2s0: send auth to 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0 (try 1/3)
[ 2625.679633] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 2625.680707] wlp2s0: associate with 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0 (try 1/3)
[ 2625.800834] wlp2s0: associate with 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0 (try 2/3)
[ 2625.858120] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 10:fe:ed:65:58:c0 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=10)
[ 2625.874661] wlp2s0: associated
[ 2640.757569] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
[ 2661.948093] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
[ 2683.154343] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
[ 2704.340696] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
```

Here is also the output of `iwconfig`:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Krizred2"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: 10:FE:ED:65:58:C0   
      Bit Rate=90 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:380  Invalid misc:627   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

and `lspci | grep Net`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
```

Kernel: Linux 3.13.6-1-ARCH

**EDIT**

Just now I noticed this, while trying to update my system, just in case, since I don't have much to lose. I tried to update my system with providing network connection with USB tethering over my mobile phone.

There I noticed that my phone gets disconnecting in a similar way than my wifi! Even with USB tethering turned off. I also tried with an USB flash key, but that seems to be working.

Comment: So your question is basically about the wireless right? Could you add the output of `iwconfig` and `lspci | grep Net`?

Comment: I REALLY hope this is the only problem...anyway, I'we edited my question

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if it's the only one, but on the stack exchange sites, you should limit yourself to one post per question which is why I asked which one you really care about. For what it's worth I've seen similar messages on my Dell and they had something to do with the "special" buttons.

Comment: Yes, I also read something about fn keys doing this, but it kinda confuses me...sorry, I hope my question isn't to broad I asked if these two can be somehow related...

Comment: No, mentioning it is useful, as you said, you never know. My comment was to make sure that the actual problem you want to solve is not the spamming of dmesg but the reconnecting wireless.

Comment: What kernel you are using?

Comment: @terdon well...all three actually :P

Comment: @Braiam Linux 3.13.6-1-ARCH

Comment: @Alko I guessed as much but having multiple questions in a single post is a quick way of having your question closed as too broad. If you focus on one thing at a time, people will be more willing to help you.

Comment: Yes I know, ok, I want to know about my wireless problem. And I also posted the other messages, since I don't know what to think of the whole situation I'm having...the last comment was kinda a joke

Comment: What driver and method to manage connections are you using?

Comment: @jasonwryan I was using `wifi-menu` and switched to KDE's Network Manager after install. I had problems in both cases. Do you think which modules are loaded? iwlwifi Else how can I get driver info?

Comment: If `iwlwifi` is loaded then check that you are only running one managing service: conflicts between two can lead to this behaviour.

Comment: @jasonwryan I'm not sure what other services there could be running. Can you tell me what I should look for?

Comment: `netctl` would be the obvious one. Scroll back through your shell history and see what you enabled...

Comment: I've searched user and root history with `history|grep netctl` and didn't get anything out. I'm pretty sure that only have NetworkManager.service and wpa_supplicant.service running in systemd. This is ok, right? I'we basically done what is written in archwiki.

Comment: Stop and disable all the network-related services and then only [enable NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager).

Comment: Hey. I have exactly the same problem. Did you solve this? How?

Comment: @Yotam have you installed Arch on UEFI FAT partition? I've reinstalled it and put my kernel on EXT and just install GRUB on UEFI partition...seems to be working a somewhat better, but the problem still persists. Also the [iwl](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=iwl) drivers have quite some bugs on that mater..

Answer (score 0):

You require to compile your own custom-kernel from the Vanilla tree to acquire that patch.

[Arch Linux First-Time Custom Kernel Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Compilation/Traditional#First-timers)

The issue with distribution-kernels is that you do not receive the benefit of the bleeding-edge tree available on Kernel.org.

The most daunting task here is to set your Kernel Flags. You also require a compiler toolchain (GCC). Your distribution, Arch, should have packages available to install for developers. When you meet that prerequisite, you will want to compile for your system.

If you have any questions about which flags you are requiring to enable, refer to the database at LKDB:

[Linux Kernel Driver Database](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/)

You need to discover what hardware in your system is supported by which kernel drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone also shows the same symptoms, it is a ***very strong*** indication that your WiFi setup is flaky, and your machine (and phone) are probably fine.

Go to the nearest WiFi hotspot (Starbucks works fine ;-) and try there.